# listing files with pattern with starting and ending

Tags: ls

I want to list all files in a directory that start with 'abc' and end with '.zip'

I'm trying to use `ls`.

The directory has a lot of zip files starting with `abc<date>` and `xvz<date>`.
I only want to get the list of the `abc<date>.zip`

Comment: `ls -1 | grep "abc$(your_date).zip"`        ?

Answer (score 24):

`ls` doesn't do pattern matching on file names. It just lists the content of the directories and the files it is being given as arguments.

Your shell on the other hand has a feature called *globbing* or *filename generation* that expands a pattern into a list of files matching that pattern.

Here that glob pattern would be `abc*.zip` (`*` being a wildcard that stands for *any number of characters*).

You'd pass it to any command you like such as `printf` for printing:

```
printf '%s\n' abc*.zip
```

You could also pass it to `ls -l` to display the attributes of those files:

```
ls -ld abc*.zip
```

(we need `-d` because if any of those files are of type *directory*, `ls` would list their content otherwise).

Or to `unzip` to extract them if only `unzip` could extract more than one file at a time. Unfortunately it doesn't, so you'd need either to use `xargs -n1` or a `for` loop:

```
printf '%s\0' abc*.zip | xargs -r0n1 unzip
```

Or:

```
for file in abc*.zip; do unzip "$file"; done
```

But in fact, `unzip` being more like a port of a MS-DOS command, `unzip` itself would treat its argument as a glob. In other words, `unzip 'abc*.zip'` will not unzip the file called `abc*.zip` (a perfectly valid file name on Unix, not on Microsoft operating systems), but the files matching the `abc*.zip` pattern, so you'd actually want:

```
 unzip 'abc*.zip'
```

<sub>(Actually our `xargs` and `for` approach above would be wrong, because if there's a file called `abc*.zip` for instance, `unzip` would treat it as a pattern! See `bsdtar` for a more unixy way to extract `zip` archives)</sub>

---

For case insensitive matching, you'd use `[aA][bB][cC]*.[zZ][iI][pP]` portably. Some shells have extended globbing operators for case insensitive matching:

- `zsh`:

  ```
  setopt extendedglob
  ls -ld (#i)abc*.zip
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  ls -ld ((#i)abc)*.zip
  ```

  if you only want the `abc` part to be case insensitive.
- `ksh93`:

  ```
  ls -ld ~(i)abc*.zip
  ```

  or:

  ```
  ls -ld ~(i:abc)*.zip
  ```
- with `bash`.

  ```
  shopt -s nocaseglob
  ls -ld abc*.zip
  ```

  (no way to have only parts of the globs case sensitive there other than by using the portable syntax).
- with `yash`:

  ```
  set +o case-glob
  ls -ld abc*.zip
  ```

  same remark as for `bash` above.

Comment: In bash `ls -ld l*.so` gives me `ls: cannot access 'l*.so': No such file or directory`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @OfekShilon, you'd need to run that from within a directory that has at least one entry whose name starts with `l` and ends in `.so` (and the `noglob` option of your shell, assuming it's POSIX-like not to be enabled).

Answer (score 17):

```
ls abc*.zip
```

This however will fail if there are too many files (there is a limit to shell expansion in term of how many arguments it can expand to).

```
find . -name "abc*.zip"
```

This is probably the most universal. The quotes must be there. With some `find` implementations, you can also use `-iname` instead of `-name` for case insensitive search (`aBc<date>.ZIP` would also match).

```
ls | grep -x "abc.*\.zip"
```

Mind the `.*` and `\.` since the filter grep uses is regex which is different from the wildcard notation the shell uses for expansion. Use `grep -i` for case insensitive search.

Comment: Note that that _limit_ is not a shell limit. It's a kernel limit in the `execve()` system call.

Comment: It should probably be noted that `find` will look for those files in subdirectories as well. Use `find . ! -name . -prune -name 'abc*.zip' -print` or `find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'abc*.zip'` if your `find` supports `-maxdepth` like on GNU or BSD or `find . -depth 1 -name 'abc*.zip'` if your `find` supports a `-depth <n>` like on some BSDs to restrict to the current directory.

Comment: `$ ls ../*.a` worked for me (list archives in parent dir).

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of `ls` to `grep`.

Let's say I want to find all files that contain `abc` in the filename

```
ls -f | grep abc
```

If you need specific variations of patterns, `man grep`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ls abc*.zip` to narrow down the results to those matching your criteria for a starting string of abc and an ending of .zip  The asterisk will expand to match those results without including xvz starting characters.

Answer (score -1):

You must specified the directory where `ls` will search in an example

```
ls -la ~/file*.* 
ls -la ./file*.*
```

it works for me, but obviously it doesn't support searching by pattern

Comment: This doesn't address the question; the files should start with `abc` and end with `.zip`.